# pumping lemma - union of regular languages

Tags: automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

In the question, we have regular languages L1, L2 with the constant of the pumping lemma - n1,n2.
Also, we have the language L = L1 + L2 with the constant n of the pumping lemma.
I need to prove that n <= max(n1,n2)
I'm really having trouble doing so.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that $m$ satisfies the pumping property for a language $L$ if the following holds :

> **pumping property for $L$ :**  For every word $w$ in $L$ of length at least $m$, $w$ can be written as $w = xyz$ where :
>   $|y| \geqslant 1$
>   $|xy| \leqslant m$
>   $\forall k \geqslant 0, \ xy^kz \in L$

Let $m := \max(n_1, n_2)$. We show that $m$ satisfies the pumping property for $L_1 \cup L_2$ :

Indeed, let $w \in L_1 \cup L_2$, then either $w \in L_1$ or $w \in L_2$. If $w \in L_1$, then since $n_1$ satisfy the pumping property for $L_1$, $m$ also satisfies the pumping property for $L_1$ (since $n_1 \leqslant m$). Hence we can write $w=xyz$ as required. Likewise if $w \in L_2$. QED

Now, $n$ just happens to be the minimum of all $p$s satisfying the pumping property for $L_1 \cup L_2$, hence $n \leqslant m = \max(n_1, n_2)$.

Comment: "pumping property for $L$" is not standard vocabulary, but it is nice don't you think?

Comment: sorry I didn't quite understand, I was given that n satisfies the pumping property for a language L, but you wrote that m does and then said that we can say that n is the  minimum of all ps satisfying the pumping property for L1∪L2, but n was given so I don't quite understand how I can say such thing

Comment: @user13084415  Given a language $L$, one needs a definition of "the constant of the pumping lemma". What does this constant do? It is given by the pumping lemma, i.e. it satisfies what I called the pumping property for $L$. But that isn't enough to make the constant unique : if $n$ works, then any $n'> n$ also works. It is good sense to define it to be the smallest integer that satisfies the pumping lemma.